# How can a token have several contracts?

Tags: tokens

I can see in CMC that there are tokens, like for example UNI, that have contracts on multiple blockchains. UNI has contracts on ethereum, binanceChain, polygon and more.
How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How is this possible?

Usually, these [tokens are bridged together](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZQJWMiX4hT0).